# How to iterate through an object that was passed from a database via ejs on the client

Tags: node.js, mongodb, ejs

My last question was marked as a duplicate which is understandable because I didn't explain it enough so now i'll explain it in more depth.

Here is my node.js server code, i'm using ejs as my template engine and mongo.js to connect to my mongo database

```
server.get('/test', (req,res) => {
    db.surveys.find((err,survey) => {
        res.render('test',{
            survey:survey
        });
    });
});
```

The object in my database that is being passed to my view is

```
[{
   "surveyCode": 123456,
   "1": {
      "question": "What is your name?",
      "1": {
         "type": "text",
         "placeholder": "Enter your name",
         "header": ""
      }
   },
   "2": {
      "question": "What grade are you in?",
      "1": {
         "type": "radio",
         "content": "9th"
      },
      "2": {
         "type": "radio",
         "content": "10th"
      },
      "3": {
         "type": "radio",
         "content": "11th"
      },
      "4": {
         "type": "radio",
         "content": "12th"
      }
   },
   "3": {
      "question": "What is your gender?",
      "1": {
         "type": "radio",
         "content": "Male"
      },
      "2": {
         "type": "radio",
         "content": "Female"
      },
      "3": {
         "type": "radio",
         "content": "Other"
      }
   }
}]
```

I've tried everything to try to iterate through the object, for Each and for loops didn't work for me. How can I iterate though the object in my view so I can separate each object and store it in a variable. Keep in mind it's an object in an object in an object, and I've tried to do a loop in a loop in a loop.

Thank You!

Comment: Maybe a loop in a loop in a loop ?

Comment: I've tried that but it didn't work, kept getting syntax errors.

Comment: Could you post that code in your question?

Comment: What do you see when you log `survey` on the client side?

Comment: I get [object] [Object] and when I try to iterate through it I get [object] [Object] again.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code showing how to access the inner members of your object:

```
var a = [
{
"1":{
"1":{
"type":"text",
"placeholder":"Enter your name",
"header":""
},
"question":"What is your name?"
},
"2":{
"1":{
"type":"radio",
"content":"9th"
},
"2":{
"type":"radio",
"content":"10th"
},
"3":{
"type":"radio",
"content":"11th"
},
"4":{
"type":"radio",
"content":"12th"
},
"question":"What grade are you in?"
},
"3":{
"1":{
"type":"radio",
"content":"Male"
},
"2":{
"type":"radio",
"content":"Female"
},
"3":{
"type":"radio",
"content":"Other"
},
"question":"What is your gender?"
},
"surveyCode":123456
}
];

for(var idx=0; idx < a.length; idx++) {
    var b = a[idx];
    for(var bkey in b) {
        var c = b[bkey];
        for(var ckey in c) {
            var d = c[ckey];
            for(var dkey in d) {
                if (typeof d === 'object') {
                    console.log(dkey);
                    console.log(d[dkey]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I know how to access the numbers in my node code but I don’t know how when it is passed to my view via ejs

Comment: You know I haven’t tried it, I ’ll try that. Can you give me an example on how to do that.

Comment: I changed the code as per your request.  You'll have to refine it a bit.